# How import and use csrf token in django 1.11?

Tags: python, django

Pease help use csrf token in django 1.11

in view.py i use follow code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf

def login(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.POST:
            username = request.POST.get('username', '')
            password = request.POST.get('password', '')
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/')
            else:
                    args['login_error'] = 'Пользователь не найден';
                    return render_to_response('login.html', args)
    else:
            return render_to_response('login.html', args)
```

but console display follow error message:

> File "/home/kalinin/django/login/views.py", line 3, in  from
>   django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf ImportError: cannot import
>   name 'csrf'

in django 1.8 i use similar code, but import csrf:

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
```

and applications is running without problems

Please help run my application for django 1.11

Comment: Django comes with [authentication views and forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). I recommend you use these, instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Django 1.8 the template context processor was moved to `django.template.context_processors.csrf`, so the import would be:

```
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
```

However, you don't need to import it at all. Stop using `render_to_response`, it's obsolete. Use the `render` shortcut instead.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

return render(request, 'login.html', args)
```

When you use the `render` shortcut, then you don't need to worry about the `csrf` token in the view, and you can remove this line.

```
args.update(csrf(request))
```