# Click a button and run a python function from views.py with JS/ajax in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I've been reading this days about how can I call a `python function` when I press a button and I'm very confused. One of the things that I saw is that I have to use `ajax` and most of the people use `jquery` to do it.

If I understood correctly the structure has to be similar to this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: '',
        data: {'A':0},
        dataType:'',
        success: function(resp){
            console.log(resp);
        }
    });
});
```

With this information, my final code is,

**views.py**

```
def vista_sumar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.POST['a']
        b = request.POST['b']
        c = int(a) + int(b)
        ctx = {'Result':c}

    return render(request,'main.html',ctx)
```

**urls.py**

```
from project.views import vista_sumar

urlpatterns = [
    path('prueba/',vista_sumar),
]
```

**main.html**

```
<input type="button" value="PRUEBA" class="boton">

<script src="{% static '/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/filters.js' %}"></script>
```

**filters.js** (the big fail)

```
$('#prueba').click(function() {
    alert('boton is working')
    a =1;
    b =3;
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/../../prueba/',
        data: {
            'a': a,
            'b': b, 
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response.Result);
        }
    }); 
});
```

I know the button is working because the first `alert` is working. The problem is when I use `ajax`.

The code error is 403=Forbbiden and is failing in the `ajax.send()`

Can somebody help me?

**EDIT**
With the help of @epikstar I solved one thing, I forgot the `CSRF`. I added in my `js file`,

```
$('#prueba').click(function() {
    alert('boton pulsado');
    var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    alert(csrftoken)
    a =1;
    b =3;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/../../prueba/',
        type: 'POST',
        headers:{"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken},
        data: {
            'a': a,
            'b': b, 
        },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        success: function(response) {
            alert('succes')
            alert(response.Result);
        }
    });
    alert('fin') 
});
```

I imported in my `views.py`

```
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
```

And I add this line in my `main.html`

```
<input type="button" value="PRUEBA" id="prueba">{% csrf_token %}
```

But it is still not working. **BUT** the problem is different because I added too a `print` in my `python function` and it shows the result 4, therefore the problem nos is that I'm not returning correctly the result.

```
def vista_sumar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.POST['a']
        b = request.POST['b']
        c = int(a) + int(b)
        ctx = {'Result':c}

        print(ctx)

    return render(request,'main.html',ctx)
```

It prints `4`

But i added a `console.log(response);`and `console.log(response.Result);` inside the `success` and don't return anything...

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/

Comment: First of all you're trying to access the `response.Result` which is not possible because you're returning an html view from your function.
Either you return `json` response from your function or create another function that returns `json` response.
Second, your `url` is incorrect in ajax request, it's not a file location, it should probably be `/prueba`.

Comment: If you just correct the `url` and alert the `response` only, you should be able to see html response in your alert.

Comment: Sorry for this silly question but can you help to correct the `response`? I'm not sure how to do it :(

Comment: when i delete the slash appears this error : `RuntimeError: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while 
maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/prueba/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings. `

Comment: as the error says, append the `/` at the end of your url, so it becomes `/prueba/`

Answer (score 0):

You should add the CSRF token like this :

```
var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
//example ajax
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
    },
    data: data,
    cache: true,
});
```

or you can add it directly from django variable :

```
 $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         headers:{
        "X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}'
         }
  })
```

take a look here to discover what csrf token does : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/csrf/

Comment: I saw this info but I thought I don't need it because I'm not using a `form`. Even so, I added your first script in my code and the error is the same. Maybe is a silly question but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: you are doing a post, so you need the CSRF. Do you import it ?

Comment: But It's necessary? because i'm using `render`. [This post says no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054699/how-import-and-use-csrf-token-in-django-1-11)

Comment: Ok i import it with `from django.template.context_processors import csrf` and I added too after my `input` this line `{% csrf_token %}` as the manual says. But is not showing the alert inside the `succes` then I have another mistake passing or recovering the variables... :(

Comment: use a console.log into your success function to ensure it passes in

Comment: is not entering in success function

Comment: then try to see if your view return what you want. print the response from the view POST

Comment: Before I wrote an edit i my post explaining what is happening now. Is not correct my `return`? Now the python function is running and receive the `js` params but is not returning it correctly. I'm so sorry but I don't understand what I have to change.

Comment: can you show what your python function returns ? also console.log the response in your js ?

Comment: I just write at the end of my post, thank you for waste your time trying help me :)